# ng-i18next translating a string placeholder

Tags: angularjs, i18next

I'm trying to translate a placeholder but the thing with this placeholder is that expects a string.

```
placeholder="'Fecha de salida'"
```

So when I try this

```
ng-i18next="[placeholder]new-trip-modal.departureDate"
```

or

```
placeholder="{{ 'new-trip-modal.departureDate' | i18next }}"
```

It doesn't work either.

Comment: hey , did you manage to solve this ?

Comment: yes actually in this case I translated in the controller!

Answer (score 0):

Placeholder's translation could be achieved in the following way:

```
<input data-ng-model="inputModel" ng-attr-placeholder="{{'some.lang.key' | i18next}}"/>
```